# OKTA sign in widget is not rendering on page routing in Angular 7 application

Tags: angular7, okta-signin-widget

I am using Angular 7.2 with @Okta/Okta-angular 1.2.1 and @okta/okta-signin-widget 2.19.0 into my angular application.

On first load of application, I am able to see the login widget but if start routing on other pages (which is not required authentication) and coming back on login page again either via app routing or via browser back button then unable to see the login okta-signin-widget. It's not re-rendering on page.

I found this problem also in okta-sign-in widget sample code. (https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular/tree/master/custom-login)

Please provide suggestion to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem after adding below code into my login component:

```
ngOnDestroy(){
      this.OktaSignInwidgetObject.remove();
  }
```

where this.OktaSignInwidgetObjectis the instance of intial configuration object:

```
 this.OktaSignInwidgetObject= new OktaSignIn(
  {
    baseUrl: 'https://{yourOktaDomain}'
    /** other Configuration*/
  }
);
```